# Getting "Social Network login failure" with linkedin using django-allauth

Tags: django, linkedin-api, django-allauth

I found **django-allauth** pretty reliable until i ran into incompressible issues. I'm using facebook and linkedin for login, while facebook login works perfectly fine but with **linkedIn** I get the following error:

```
Social Network Login Failure
An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.
```

I'm trying to connect multiple social accounts to same email but then I tried login with a new user and I still got the same error with LinkedIn. Im completely lost here, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn has updated its APIs and Scopes that you can ask permissions for. Please refer to their official site. I removed `r_fullprofile` and instead used `r_basicprofile` which solved my problem.